# Regex for a user name in Javascript a name not a username

Tags: javascript, regex

i have been trying with this for a while and failing, not that good with regex, what i need is the following:

A user name (the name of the person not a username)

it can include - because some names have hyphen in them (max of 2 allowed)

it can include a space (up to 3)

it cannot include numbers and must start with a letter not a hyphen

it must be at least 3 chars and 30 max

it must accommodate to people with non English letters (e.g. Agnès)

I tried this but it failed, it allowed starting with a number and did not 
accept non English letters like è or ï

```
^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,30}$
```

Any help would be highly appreciated and I think this will help many programmers searching SO

Comment: Don't use `[a-zA-Z-]` but `\D` (or the equivalent `[^0-9]`)

Comment: This is a task better not solved with regex anyway.

Comment: You either need to use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/) or build a custom Unicode letter class.

Comment: With XRegExp you can build a pattern like [`^(?!(?:[^ ]* ){4})(?!(?:[^-]*-){3})\p{L}[\p{L} -]{2,29}$`](https://regex101.com/r/GQi1Dy/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the answer:

```js
/** Check if name is valid.
 * @param {String} name
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
const validateName = (name) => {
    name = name.trim().replace(/\s+/, ' ')
    if (name.length > 30 || name.length < 3) return false // length is too long or too short
    if ((name.match(/-/g) || []).length > 2) return false // more than 2 '-' found
    if ((name.match(/\s+/g) || []).length > 3) return false // more than 3 'whitespace chains' found
    if (name.match(/[~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\d[\]{}\\|:;"'<>,.\/?]/)) return false // not alowed char found
    name = name.split(/\s+/g)
    for (let part of name)
        if (part[0] === '-') return false // part of name starts with -

    return true
}

console.log(`Agnès Jaszenko: ${validateName("Agnès Jaszenko")}`) // valid
console.log(`Ag: ${validateName("Ag")}`) // too short
console.log(`Aga-ta roko-la-foo: ${validateName("Aga-ta roko-la-foo")}`) // too many -
console.log(`Agata Jolanta Krzyżtofska-Brzęczyszczewiczykówna: ${validateName("Agata Jolanta Krzyżtofska-Brzęczyszczewiczykówna")}`) // to long
console.log(`   Pan     Janusz   Kocioł  : ${validateName("   Pan     Janusz   Kocioł  ")}`) // valid
console.log(`Maciej Kozieja: ${validateName("Maciej Kozieja")}`) // fancy :3 hah :P - valid
console.log(`-Łarjusz Miętocha: ${validateName("-Łarjusz Miętocha")}`) // starting with -
console.log(`Łarjusz@ Miętocha: ${validateName("Łarjusz@ Miętocha")}`) // not alowed char
console.log(`محمد: ${validateName("محمد")}`) // valid with arabic symbols
console.log(`مح1مد: ${validateName("مح1مد")}`) // not valid char found
```

You can modify this code and return information to user about what is invalid or just use it like this.
Hope it works for you :D

### How it works?

**step 1** `.trim()` removes all whitespace at begining and end.
**step 2** `.replace(/\s+/, ' ')` replace all whitespace left with exacly one space (doing this allows for `'Name        Name'` to be valid and 'reduces length' - actual count of words)
**step 3** `name.length > 30 || name.length < 3` checking the length
**step 4** `name.match(/-/g)` counting '-'
*sadly while thers no count matches and simple name.match(/-/g).length would break when no match was found thats why we have to use this 'trick' with 'default value'*
**step 5** `name.match(/\s+/g)` counting whitespaces
**step 6** `` name.match(/[~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\d[\]{}\\|:;"'<>,.\/?]/) `` checking if name contains any of not alowed chars
Sadly as you know `\d` is not enough to check for all languages but you can reverse this proces and check if name contains any of not allowed chars
**step 7** check if part of word begins with -
**step 8** if all tests passed your name is valid and `true` is returned :)

### Live Preview:

```js
/** Check if name is valid.
 * @param {String} name
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
const validateName = (name) => {
    name = name.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    if (name.length > 30 || name.length < 3) return false // length is too long or too short
    if ((name.match(/-/g) || []).length > 2) return false // more than 2 '-' found
    if ((name.match(/\s+/g) || []).length > 3) return false // more than 3 'whitespace chains' found
    if (name.match(/[~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\d[\]{}\\|:;"'<>,.\/?]/)) return false // not alowed char found
    name = name.split(/\s+/g)
    for (let part of name)
        if (part[0] === '-') return false // part of name starts with -

    return true
}

const input = document.createElement('input')
const valid = document.createElement('p')
input.addEventListener('keyup', () =>{
  valid.innerHTML = validateName(input.value)
})
document.body.append(input)
document.body.append(valid)
```