# Javascript validation regex for names

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to accept names in my app with letters and hyphens or dashes, i based my code on an answer i found here
and coded that:

```
function validName(n){
  var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
  if(n.match(nameRegex) == null){
    return "Wrong";
  }
  else{
    return "Right";
  }
}
```

the only problem is that it accepts hyphen as the first letter (even multiple ones) which i don't want.
thanks

Comment: Should your app accept `George Henry` as a name? If so, you have to allow spaces. And what about `Gérard Depardieu`? Or `محمد` (Mohammed)?

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks for the thought but i asked a question about this days ago and didn't get any answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074834/regex-for-a-user-name-in-javascript-a-name-not-a-username?noredirect=1#comment71328204_42074834), it doesn't seem possible, so i thought i keep it simple and O'Reilly and محمد have to write OReily and Mohammed unfortunately, if you have a solution or a guide to this please let me know

Comment: and of course i still have the issue of spaces, some write Marry Anne others write Marry-Anne

Comment: See my answer. It is much simpler than the answer you accepted and shows how to extend the solution. You do not really need any lookaheads here.

Comment: I answered [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074834/regex-for-a-user-name-in-javascript-a-name-not-a-username/42174979#42174979)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decompose your single character class into 2 , moving the hyphen outside of it and use a grouping construct to match sequences of the hyphen + the alphanumerics:

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PUBviV/1)

This will match alphanumeric chars (1 or more) at the start of the string and then will match 0 or more occurrences of `-` + one or more alphanumeric chars up to the end of the string.

If there can be only 1 hyphen in the string, replace `*` at the end with `?` (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQAMp1/1)).

If you also want to allow whitespace between the alphanumeric chars, replace the `-` with `[\s-]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bupPoh/1)).

Answer (score 4):

Use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matching the string starting with a hyphen. Although there is no need to escape `-` in the character class when provided at the end of character class. Use `-` removed character class for avoiding `-` at ending or use lookahead assertion.

```
var nameRegex = /^(?!-)[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]$/;
// or
var nameRegex = /^(?!-)(?!.*-$)[a-zA-Z-]+$/;
```

```js
var nameRegex = /^(?!-)[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]$/;
// or
var nameRegex1 = /^(?!-)(?!.*-$)[a-zA-Z-]+$/;

function validName(n) {
  if (n.match(nameRegex) == null) {
    return "Wrong";
  } else {
    return "Right";
  }
}

function validName1(n) {
  if (n.match(nameRegex1) == null) {
    return "Wrong";
  } else {
    return "Right";
  }
}

console.log(validName('abc'));
console.log(validName('abc-'));
console.log(validName('-abc'));
console.log(validName('-abc-'));
console.log(validName('a-b-c'));

console.log(validName1('abc'));
console.log(validName1('abc-'));
console.log(validName1('-abc'));
console.log(validName1('-abc-'));
console.log(validName1('a-b-c'));
```

**FYI :** You can use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method for searching regex match and which returns boolean based on regex match.

```
if(nameRegex.test(n)){
  return "Right";
}
else{
  return "Wrong";
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want only single optional `-` in between words, then use a 0 or more repetitive group which starts with `-`as in *@WiktorStribiżew* answer .

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
```

Comment: That's what I was going to write. But you can avoid escaping dash (`-`) if it is at the end of the set (not mandatory, though).

Comment: it is still accepting a dash at the end, i know i didn't mention that in my question but please guide on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a negative lookahead like Pranav C Balan propsed or just use this simple expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z-]*$
```

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/Dj0eTH/1

Comment: Hmm.. this regex silently passes something like `sdfs----safasf`, while [**`Pranav C Balan's answer works perfectly`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174375/javascript-validation-regex-for-names#answer-42174400).

Answer (score 0):

The below regex is useful for surnames if one wants to forbid leading or trailing non-alphabetic characters, while permitting a small set of common word-joining characters in between two names.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[- ']{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^[a-zA-Z]+` must begin with at least one letter
- `[- ']{0,1}` allow zero or at most one of any of `-`,   or `'`
- `[a-zA-Z]+$` must end with at least one letter

**Test cases**

(The double-quotes have been added purely to illustrate the presence of whitespace.)

```
"Blair"         => match
" Blair"        => no match
"Blair "        => no match
"-Blair"        => no match
"- Blair"       => no match
"Blair-"        => no match
"Blair -"       => no match
"Blair-Nangle"  => match
"Blair--Nangle" => no match
"Blair Nangle"  => match
"Blair -Nangle" => no match
"O'Nangle"      => match
"BN"            => match
"BN "           => no match
" O'Nangle"     => no match
"B"             => no match
"3Blair"        => no match
"!Blair"        => no match
"van Nangle"    => match
"Blair'"        => no match
"'Blair"        => no match
```

Limitations include:

- No single-character surnames
- No surnames composed of more than two words

[Check it out on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ouUmCb/1).