# Why the name validation is invalid?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, google-chrome

Why the name is not valid when user is type:

```
André
René
François
Anne-Marie
```

CODE:

```
var myNameFilter = /^([a-zA-Z ]+)$/;
var a = $('#firstname').val();
if(a=='') {
  alert("You stupid your name is empty. Fill it in NOW!!!");
  return false;

} else if (!myNameFilter.test(a)) {
    alert("Are you stupid? how can you type your name wrong. you idiot. fix it, dont call me for this.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: because all these names contain characters not matched by your character class: `é`, `ç` and `-`

Comment: How can i allow all those none standard characters? (all those french, dutch people have awkward characters).

Comment: Name validation is a hard task and there will always be a name that kills your regex: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074834/regex-for-a-user-name-in-javascript-a-name-not-a-username/42174979#42174979) - name validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[a-zA-Z] detect only english. they contain unicode characters and so it will not detect it.
Now check it

```js
var a="André,René,Fran çois,Anne-Marie,éç,é-çé ç,Éric,Hélène".split(",");
var myNameFilter = /^([a-zA-Z\-éçèàùâêîôûëïüÿçÉ\s]+)$/;
i=0;
while(i<a.length){
 console.log(a[i]+"->"+myNameFilter.test(a[i]));
  i++;
}
```

Comment: now check `Fran çois` has a space and it is also detected

Comment: it working . check again

Comment: What about `Éric`, `Hélène`

Comment: you have to add those special characters in order to match it. For system, they are not letters. They are special characters

Comment: you have to add every symbol.

Comment: Excellent work!!! very nice validation

Comment: As a German this makes me sad, no "Umlauts" :)